# Jackson cannot convert String to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class such as

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class AState {
    AName name;
    String message;
    OffsetDateTime updatedAt;


public AssetStatusState() {
  }
}
//getters and setters follow
```

which is imported as a maven dependency in my project. In my project, I receive a JSON String from an event bus and I try to parse that to an object of type `AState`. The JSON string is of the form :

```
{"name":"comps", "message":"ok", "updatedAt":"2020-03-05T02:31:17.683Z"}
```

I try to parse this by :

```
this.objectMapper.convertValue(someString, AState.class)
```

When I'm constructing my main object, I also do

```
this.objectMapper.register(new JavaTimeModule());
```

But I'm still unable to resolve this error - I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can someone please help?

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Cannot construct instance of `java.time.OffsetDateTime` 
(no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method 
to deserialize from String value ('2020-03-05T02:31:17.683Z')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
```

However, in a standalone test, the deserialization works like a charm. Is there an issue with the JSON string?

Comment: try readValue method: this.objectMapper.readValue(someString, AState.class)

Comment: @User9123 I just realised, I'm actually trying to convert a LinkedHashMap to AState.class